# Problem with a for in my DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called `trip_cost` and I want to create a new column called `level`.

I am doing this:

```
df['level'] = ''
for i in df.trip_cost:
    if i < 65.0:
        df['Nivel'] = 'low'
    
    elif 65.0 <= i <= 82.0:
        df['Nivel'] = 'medium'
    
    else:
        df['Nivel'] = 'high'
```

The problem is that all the column is getting the level `'low'`instead of the others when it should..

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Assigning `df['Nivel']` assigns that field in every row. It seems like you expect it to just do the current row of the `for` loop, but how would it know what that row is?

Comment: As a general rule, if you're looping over a dataframe you're probably doing something wrong, since Pandas has built-in operations to filter and update.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you apply it on whole column, so probably your last record has trip_cost < 65. I suggest something like this:

```py
def label_nivel (row):
   if row['trip_cost'] < 65:
      return 'low'
   if row['trip_cost'] < 82:
      return 'medium'
   return 'high'
   
df['Nivel'] df.apply (lambda row: label_race(row), axis=1)
```